# node.js app deployment using pm2 without downtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pm2

There are tons of tutorial how to develop chat application using socket.io and node.js and no doubt event driven advantage of node has the advantage of doing chat application. But recently this thought came into my mind, how can I sustain my chat app when I deploy the app? imagine there are thousand of users are actively chatting in it.

in this article https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-cluster-mode-and-zero-downtime-restarts clearly state that cluster technqiue required extra cares, hmm is there any way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

PM2 is not the right tool for this. It's great, but too limited for that kind of orchestration.

The best solution is structure your server behind load balancers and running parallel instances of the application taking turns to handle the incoming requests. This is one of the most common use cases for containers like [Docker](https://docker.com).

A great example (the one I'm currently using under production in a dating-app with a socket.io based chat) is the mesosphere's [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/) and [Marathon LB](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb). We have them running in AWS, behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

You can actually get something like this with [Heroku](https://heroku.com) but may be a little harder because you'll be limited by their Load Balancer features. In socket.io you can use a Redis session driver to handle the distributed sessions.

Comment: restart take about few sec. I tested my chat app. it worked as usual. i think it will have down time for split second, but the previous established socket did not collapse.

Comment: socket.io with redis for session? u need session using socket.io?

Comment: You are correct but if you need to update the PM2 itself, the downtime is greater than that. If you need to update the NodeJS itsel, the same. If you need, for any reason, to reboot the machine, you loose all clustered instances. That's why I said PM2 is not the best tool for this (and got a downvote). It's a great start, but as you said "thousands of users" are relying on it. I would never, EVER, use PM2 for a project with so many users. Event if it's running a cluster of node instances, it's still a single point of failure away of complete downtime.

Comment: About the Redis Session, if you want parallel instances of the same code using Sockets you need a centralized session storage (event for clusters in a single PM2). Check the socket.io official docs for NodeJS Clusters (http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#using-node.js-cluster).